# Soy nuevo xfa ayudenme con código de python para agregar una condición

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación y me interesa mucho. Les quería por favor pedir ayuda con este código de Python. La pregunta es que debo agregar para que al ejecutar el programa e ingresar por ejemplo un string en vez de un numero, no arroje error ValueError y en vez de ello, aparezca un print ("el caracter no es valido") y vuelva a iterar el proceso hasta que se ingrese un numero?? Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
import math 

print('Vamos a calcular la raiz cuadrada de un numero')
print("""   """)
i=float(input('Introduzca un numero '))


while i>0: 
    solucion=math.sqrt(i)
    print("""   """)
    print('La raiz cuadrada de ' + str(i) + ' es ' + str(solucion))
    print("""   """)
    i=float(input('Introduzca un numero '))

while i<=0: 
    print("""   """)
    print('No se puede calcular la raiz de cero o de un numero negativo')
    print("""   """)
    i=int(input('Introduzca un numero valido '))
    while i>0: 
        solucion=math.sqrt(i)
        print("""   """)
        print('La raiz cuadrada de ' + str(i) + ' es ' + str(solucion))
        print("""   """)
        i=float(input('Introduzca un numero '))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta!! me funciono genial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo ver como manejar las [Excepciones en Python](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/errors.html) pues ese es el tema que quieres manejar. Por lo tanto para controlar ese tipo de errores muchos lenguajes de programación adoptan técnicas y Python no es la excepción. Utilizaremos `try`  que se entiende como advertencia de posible error en las siguientes lineas de código  y `except` que seria la solución solo si es que ocurre el error. Entonces agregamos un ciclo infinito (Hasta que ingrese un numero) para leer el dato y segun ingrese una cadena inmediatamente pasara el bloque del `except` . Este seria el codigo final:

```
import math

print('Vamos a calcular la raiz cuadrada de un numero')
print("""   """)

while True:
    try:
        i=float(input("Introduzca un numero: "))
        while i>0: 
            solucion=math.sqrt(i)
            print("""   """)
            print('La raiz cuadrada de ' + str(i) + ' es ' + str(solucion))
            print("""   """)
            i=float(input('Introduzca un numero '))

        while i<=0: 
            print("""   """)
            print('No se puede calcular la raiz de cero o de un numero negativo')
            print("""   """)
            i=int(input('Introduzca un numero valido '))
            while i>0: 
                solucion=math.sqrt(i)
                print("""   """)
                print('La raiz cuadrada de ' + str(i) + ' es ' + str(solucion))
                print("""   """)
                i=float(input('Introduzca un numero '))
        break

    except BaseException:
        print("""   """)
        print("No se puede ingresar una letra, vuelva a ingresar un numero")
        print("""   """)
```

Comment: Si es la respuesta a tu pregunta puedes marcarme como solución.

Comment: Es recomendable que en `try` pongas solo el código que se va a evaluar, es decir el `input` que pide el número. Si pones tanto código como en tu ejemplo, en caso de que algo mas envíe una excepción sería mas difícil de diagnosticar

Comment: mil gracias amigo